# why immutable programming is preferred than mutable?

Tags: multithreading, scala, immutability

what i am getting from all the [available article](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151733/if-immutable-objects-are-good-why-do-people-keep-creating-mutable-objects) about this topic is,

The main advantage of immutable objects is to make the concurrent programming.
so if any application uses so many threads then we can use immutability.

here my question is: **if application don't require multiple threads, still the immutable programming is preferred? because creating a new copy of the object for every single change can be very costly.** (if yes why)

Comment: Re, "creating a new copy of the object for every single change can be very costly."  Yup.  And writing code that is difficult to understand and change also has costs (we call that "technical debt").  What we get paid for is weighing the costs and deciding which way is the best way to solve any particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this:

```
class Time(t: Double) {
  private var time = t // Danger: mutable field
  def getTime = time
  def setTime(t: Double): Unit = time = t
}

val startAt = new Time(5.0)
val someOtherTime = startAt
someOtherTime.setTime(10.0)

// What does startAt.getTime return?
```

In this simple example, you might (or might not) be surprised to learn that, after `someOtherTime.setTime(10.0)` returns, `startAt.getTime` will have the value `10.0` instead of `5.0`. Did you expect that, particularly given that `startAt` is a `val`?

Given that you've seen the code, maybe that was to be expected. However, if you just used `Time` without looking at its internals, I'm guessing that you'd be very surprised by that behavior. The state of mutable objects can change without you being aware of the change - particularly in a multi-threaded environment, where access to `Time.time` must be synchronized - but even the single-threaded case can introduce unexpected complexity.

Keeping objects immutable makes them simple to reason about. When those objects represent *value types*, immutability is practically essential. (Name a single value type in any major programming language or library that is not immutable.)

One further point about single-threaded vs. multi-threaded coding: if you're writing a single-threaded application, you might be tempted to ignore thread safety as an issue altogether. However, I think that's a little short-sighted in the general case. All new processors have multiple cores, and indications are that processors are going to get more and more cores in the coming years. If you want to write responsive, high-performance code, you're going to need to write multi-threaded applications, using thread-safe libraries.

If you're writing code that is not thread safe, and if it contains a lot of mutable objects exhibiting *shared mutable state*, then you're going to have to do a huge amount of refactoring to make it suitable for use in multi-threaded applications. On the other hand, if your objects are immutable, and have no shared mutable state, then that job is going to be a whole lot easier.

Incidentally, it is perfectly possible to use mutable state in a function, class, etc. provided that the mutable state is not shared (i.e. visible externally). That way you can have the benefits of the performance of mutable state, without the drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree that immutable objects are simpler to reason about, even in single threaded programs. However sometimes it's more practical to work with mutable data, for example if performance is crucial (our computers are optimized for mutating operations) or the library you're using is inherently stateful.

I would also add that Scala is not the best language for writing pure functional programs. Languages like Haskell, PureScript, Idris etc. are better suited for the task IMHO. For some multi-threaded programs it's definitely worth the extra hassle to write Scala programs in a purely functional way though.